# Starting tasks inside of enumerate causes text overlap

Tags: spacing, pdftex, enumerate, multicol, tasks

I'm trying to create an answer key using the tasks environment (I had previously used a combination of enumerate and multicols). Basically, I want the answer key to look like this:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{enumerate}
        \begin{multicols}{3}
            \item A1
            \item A2
            \item A3
            \item A4
            \item A5
            \item A6
        \end{multicols}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
```

which produces:
[image]

except numbered horizontally. To do this, I use tasks:

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item
    \begin{tasks}(3)
        \task A1
        \task A2
        \task A3
        \task A4
        \task A5
        \task A6
    \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}
```

which instead produces:

[image]

with the enumerate and the task headers stuck together.

Comment: You may with to change the indentation as shown in the manual.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. Are you referring to the code that I've used in the question? And to which manual are you referring?

Comment: You can find the documentation for the `tasks` package at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tasks/tasks_en.pdf

Comment: Ah, yes. I've tried playing with the indentation options etc. They actually seem to just pull the enumerate header over further with the first tasks header, so that the two are always on top of one another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no problem with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
 \usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tasks}

\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}[label =1.]
    \item\mbox{}\vspace*{-\dimexpr\baselineskip + \topsep}
    \begin{tasks}(3)
        \task A1
        \task A2
        \task A3
        \task A4
        \task A5
        \task A6
    \end{tasks}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]