# Uneven vertical space with enumerate and multicols

Tags: spacing, enumerate, multicol, vertical-spacing, babel-french

I'm having a vertical spacing glitch in this minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
\usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item %Blabla
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),itemsep=11pt]
            \item This is a simple test.
            \item This is a simple test.
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \smallskip % Without this command, the spacing is too small!
    \item %Blabla
        \begin{multicols}{2}
        \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*),itemsep=11pt]
            \item This is a simple test.
            \item This is a simple test.
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{multicols}
    \smallskip
    \item Blabla bla blabla bla bla bla blabla.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Preview of what this code is doing, and the glitch shown in red:
[image]

The space indicated in red is too big, compared to the green one.  It's uneven and I don't understand why.  If I remove the `\smallskip` command, it's then too small.  If I remove the `babel` package (which I don't want to do!), then the issue is solved.

So what am I doing wrong here?  How can I fix this issue, while keeping the french babel command?

Note that I need to keep the multicols environments inside the enumerate.  The full document has lots of them.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/7229/134144 could be useful.

Comment: As an alternative to the multicolumn +  nested enumerate environment approach, you could use a `tasks` environment inside of `enumerate`. For an example see here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378651/134144

Comment: This is a problem with the redefinitions done to the list environments by babels french option. They somehow result in not seeing properly what spaces are already around and thus ending up adding the wrong one. your problem goes away when you change from "french" to say "english" in babel (or take it out). My suggestion is to talk to Daniel the maintainer of the french option of babel as you say you need the french option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`babel-french` customizes vertical spacing in lists (i.e. `\itemsep`,
`\parsep`, `\partopsep`, `\topsep`) when French is the main language, but
provides an option `\frenchsetup{StandardListSpacing}` to revert to the
standard settings.

In this example, `enumitem` is loaded. It enables a far better control on
lists than `babel-french`, so I strongly recommend to use option
`StandardListSpacing` and let `enumitem` *alone* customize lists.

The glitch mentioned vanishes with `\frenchsetup{StandardListSpacing}`. Actually, the vertical space above item 3 is reduced by `babel-french` (without this option) which looks wrong, the one between items 1 and 2 is unchanged.

Comment: How do you add this option? At which place in the code?  I’m getting compilation errors if I add it to the preamble or inside the enumerate environment.

Comment: You have to add it in the preambule and after \usepackage[french]{babel}. If your installation is a bit old, you can try \frenchbsetup{StandardListSpacing} instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* a solution to the problem which is I think a bug in the french ldf file for babel, but if you are contend with less space what seem to work is to reduce the extra space that multicol adds above and below of the environment, e.g., add

```
\AddToHook{env/enumerate/begin}{\setlength\multicolsep{\itemsep}}
```

to your preamble.
But as I said, this need to be looked at from the babel code which I think has a bug here.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if this is what you need, but by simply adding an itemsep in the first enumerate helps

[image: My code output]

```
 \documentclass[11pt,twoside]{book}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage[french]{babel} % Removing this command rise some vertical space!
    \usepackage{microtype,textcomp}
    \usepackage[total={6.25in,10in},left=1.25in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
    \usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{multicol}
\begin{document}
    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=11pt]
        \item
            \begin{multicols}{2}
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
                \item TTTTTTTTTTTT
                \item TTTTTTTTTTTT
            \end{enumerate}
            \end{multicols}
     \item
            \begin{multicols}{2}
            \begin{enumerate}[label=\alph*)]
                \item TTTTTTTTTTTT
                \item TTTTTTTTTTTT
            \end{enumerate}
            \end{multicols}
    \item TTTTTTTTTTTT
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, this answer doesn’t consider the issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I find this a bit pityful that 2 people have downvoted this answer (not a common occurance in this forum). It may not have *solved* the underlying issue, which is a bug in the french .ldf but it gives a reasonable workaround.

Comment: Tbf I had misunderstood the problem, so it has been edited, which is probably why it got downvoted